# bitwise operations in recursive function using C

Tags: c, recursion, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

So I'm pretty new to working with C and I'm taking an online course that provides me with exercises to practice with.

What I'm trying to do is take a long data type and return an int value according to it's binary representation. The rule is if the 2 most-right bits are different from zero (01, 10, 11) count this as one and move to the next 2 bits and so on.
For example:

00000000-00000000-00000000-000000**01**- should return 1.

00000000-000000**11**-000000**01**-000000**10**- should return 3.

0000**10**00-**11**0000**11**-0000**1001**-00**11**00**10**- should return 7.

```
int abcLength(long abcCode) {
  if(abcCode&3) {   /*** <--- Try to do this using only bitwise and logical operators !  ***/
    return 0;
  }
  return 1 + abcLength((((unsigned)abcCode>>2)); /*** <--- Try to do this using only bitwise and logical operators !  ***/
}
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to deal with cases that have **00** in the middle of the binary string. They told me to use only one if statement but as it is now it would count **00** when it shouldn't.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- you return `0` immediately when one of the 2 low bits is set. This is incorrect. You should return `0` if the argument is 0 and add one the recursion value if the 2 low bits are non `0`.
- you cast `abcCode` as `(unsigned)` when recursing, which may mask off the most significant bits. You should cast as `(unsigned long)` instead.

Here is a modified version:

```
int abcLength(long abcCode) {
    int n = 0;
    if (abcCode == 0)
        return 0;
    if (abcCode & 3)
        n++;
    return n + abcLength((unsigned long)abcCode >> 2);
}
```

This can be obfuscated as:

```
int abcLength(long code) {
    return code ? !!(code & 3) + abcLength((unsigned long)code >> 2) : 0;
}
```

Here is a solution with a loop:

- combine the bits in even and odd positions
- iterate to count the number of bytes with a low bit set

Simple implementation:

```
int abcLength(long x) {
    unsigned long code = x;
    int n;
    for (n = 0; code != 0; code >>= 2) {
        if (code & 3)
            n++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

And here is a potentially faster one without any loops:

```
int abcLength(long code) {
    code = (code | (code >> 1)) & 0x5555555555555555;
    code = (code + (code >> 2)) & 0x3333333333333333;
    code = (code + (code >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F0F0F0F0F;
    return (code * 0x101010101010101) >> 56;
}
```

Comment: No I'm absolutley sure it should be move 2 places.. maybe the example wasn't clear enough.
**10**000000-0000**11**00-00**11**00**10**-**11**0000**01** - should return 6
So shifting the entire byte would make me lose counting. @chqrlie

Comment: Also it doesn't matter if the input value is negative ot not. The point of the task is to relate to every 2 individual bits inside the 8 bytes that hold the long value.

Comment: @RONOLULU "The rule is if the 2 most-right bits are different from zero"?

Comment: @DavidSais "The rule is if the 2 most-right bits are different from zero" is followed **by**  "count this as one and move to the next 2 bits and so on"

Comment: Oh, so that is what `!!` is for... now I understand.

Comment: @DavidSais: `!x` is equivalent to `x == 0`, and `!!x` is the same as `!(!x)` ie: `x != 0`. Both evaluate to boolean values `0` or `1`.